# Issue with downloading Windows10 virtual machine for Virtual Box

Tags: macos, virtualbox, windows-10, microsoft-edge

This is the fourth time I've downloaded the VM from [here](https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/). Once it's done and I extract the .zip file, it comes out as a .czip file which if you unzip again becomes a .zip file. It's like an endless loop of zipping/unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't to zip or unzip your file, look at this link: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/198427-how-to-install-windows-10-in-a-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the ISO instead and installed it manually after following [this](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/198427-how-to-install-windows-10-in-a-virtual-machine) guide.